# Aligned AI Used By Misaligned Humans

Tags: humans, artificial-intelligence, bio-weapons

Title.
In my story idea, an extremist terror group uses an advanced AI to create a designer disease that ultimately kills ~20% of the world's population. This ultimately leads to humans banning all sufficiently advanced AI.

If a designer disease of that level of devastation was created by AI, is it plausible that humans would ban all advanced AI, or is it more likely
that it would be banned in only biological/bioengineering areas, or would something else entirely happen?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: First you say that the problem has been solved, than you ask if to avoid that problem humans would do something....

Comment: @L.Dutch No. What I said is that humans aligned their AIs in that they now have AI that follows human orders and objectives. That is what I mean by "AI alignment has been solved".

The problem the humans face is humans using advanced AI for malicious objectives. Not related to AI alignment. Completely different problem.

Comment: Like L.Dutch I can't understand your issue at hand. If you want it banned in your world, then it has been banned in your world and there's no reason to worry it might not be banned, be it everywhere or in specific domains. Indeed, it's a worldbuilding (and perhaps narrative too) choice as an author, not a constraint with other in-world elements :).

Comment: Humans have never successfully banned a technology, individual  governments have only barely managed it. all they have ever managed to do is lose tech that has no use anymore.

Comment: You may want to consider that most people would **not** see the disease as created by the tool, but rather by the people who used the tool. Most people say that *Mona Lisa* was painted by Leonardo da Vinci, not by the paintbrush of Leonardo da Vinci. Most people say that *David* was sculpted by Michelangelo, not by the chisel of Michelangelo. Most people say that *Harry Potter* was written by J. K. Rowling, not by Ms. Rawling's copy of Microsoft Word or by Ms. Rawling's computer.

Comment: @AlexP Clearly you've never seen the gun control debate. XD

Comment: @stix: As far as I know, the gun control "debate" is something specific to the USA, where for some obscure reasons the constitutional provision of the right to bear arms has been interpreted as the right to own and use pistols instead of the obvious intended meaning of making America a land of [armigerous](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/armigerous) citizens by allowing everybody to display a coat of arms. (The point being that the American Constitution does not explain whether by [arms](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/arms) it refers to weapons or to heraldic designs.)

Comment: You can't use an AI to *create* a designer disease. You could use it to *design* one, but making the actual, physical disease organism from that design is a far more complex, far more easily restricted process.

Comment: The question asks for plausibility (author's job, not ours) and for opinions: Do we feel that alternative A, B, or C is most likely? I don't quite see how this is on-topic for Worldbuilding. Ask the leaders of the society you created what their motivations are when this crisis occurs.

Comment: According to some mainstream political theories, this did happen and is currently happening. Did we ban anything? Well, some places banned people from trying to avoid catching the disease... yikes.

Comment: @user535733 
I know that feasibility is the author's job. I was trying to write a story in which AI technology advances significantly but then gets banned/rolled back/massively regresses for some reason, but specifically without a robot uprising. The reason why I was posting my premise here is because I was unsure if it could lead to an AI regression and wanted a second opinion.

Comment: @Tortliena Yes, I know it is my world, and I can do whatever I want with it. But I wanted a sequence of events that could plausibly happen to stop it from being contrived.

Comment: @AlexP That is perhaps the most creatively incorrect interpretation I have ever heard. Kudos.

Answer (score 7):

## Frame Challenge - The Tool Isn't The Problem, and Cannot Be Put Away

Dune-style *Butlerian Jihad* stuff aside, bans have never worked for anything that is easy to make.  (And personally, I think the Dune stuff was only plausible in the mind of Mr. Herbert because computers were *not* easy to make at the time he wrote it.)

Prohibition did not *fail*, per se, but it certainly didn't prevent anyone who wanted alcohol from getting some.  It *did* mean that forcing the production underground provided more power to people who were by design criminals.

Moreover, it's not as if AI is a) required, or b) the only tool involved in your hypothetical situation.  A research lab with incentive could readily come up with any variety of hybridized bioweapons today, without any sort of true AI.

So problem 1: prohibition is basically impossible.  Computer data is much, much easier to smuggle than centrifuges and nuclear precursors.  It's also a safe bet that its power consumption is not going to be something that draws any attention in an industrialized society. So anyone (individual, corporation, state actor) who is inclined to be a criminal and run an AI will have no problem doing so unless the world is under a unified draconian police state.  With this plainly evident, no one is going to *suggest* a ban, because a ban you can't enforce without an Orwellian surveillance state is not a useful ban.  (As an example, it was illegal - it qualified as munitions sales - to sell strong encryption from the US to people in other countries.  [So they published it as a book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy#Criminal_investigation).)

Problem #2 is very much a slippery-slope argument: It's a safe bet that far more crucial to the design of this superbug wasn't the AI that designed it, but the biological editing processes (the future equivalent of CRISPR/CAS-9) that allowed its assembly.  So why AI rather than this more specialized tool?  Why not both?  The counter-argument is easy: these tools are doubtless extraordinarily important in pharmaceutical design and other biological research.  So too would AI be, so the counterargument to a ban is the same.

Far more likely than a ban would be an *expansion* of the use of AI to get ahead of isolated terrorist groups.  Much like gain-of-function research today, AIs in bioscience would iterate through thousands of hypothetical superbugs, coming up with treatments and vaccines for anything of which lesser, less-well-provisioned labs could conceive.

This would have a *lot* of public support, and researchers would likely lean even harder on AI in the wake of a plague that left 1 in 5 of their colleagues dead.

**Summing up**: I think that the central thesis of the *question* (would AI be banned in general, or just in certain applications?) is immersion-breaking on its face, and so logically inconsistent that it cannot be meaningfully answered.

*However*... if in your world computer technology is very different, and a trillion-dollar factory is required to make "AI cores" which are the only hardware on which an AI can run... it becomes slightly more plausible, with point #1, at least, being obviated.

Comment: So to be clear your answer is "no, it would not likely be banned, on the contrary?"

Comment: @Tortliena In part.  I also think that the focus on AI is, on its face, silly, and that hanging the worldbuilding on it requires a _lot_ of counterfactual stuff.

Good point, though, I should sum up.

Comment: I think this is mostly right, but rapid loss of 20% of the world's population is a civilization ending event on its own (and the population crash wouldn't stop at -20%). Civilization ending solutions merit consideration, as does the possibility that things might be hard to make that were previously easy.

Comment: @Jdunlop Yes, I wasn't sure if you (rightly) gave an answer after your frame-challenge, or if it was even a frame challenge at all ^^"

Comment: @gs - you may be right (certainly you're right about a 20% population loss being civilization-ending, but I have to imagine the automation implied by general AI being a available would make industrialization loss less likely).  But any argument about things being harder to make post-apocalypse is going to trend harder on "biological lab equipment" than "things you can run on any functional computer equipment".

Comment: @jdunlop
Can you suggest a premise in which it could be banned then? I was trying to write a story in which AI gets banned/massively regresses for some reason that does not involve the usual robot uprising scenario, as I wanted to keep the focus on humans. I wrote this question because I was unsure of the plausibility of my scenario of "AI-assisted plague = ban" and wanted a second opinion.
I apologize for insufficient detail or logical inconsistencies: I am new to this.

Comment: @1001 - does it have to exist in the first place?  It could be as simple as humans discovering that true AI is actually impossible, that LLMs are as good as we'll ever get.  Alternately, a big ol' solar flare aimed directly at earth would fry an _enormous_ percentage of our most sophisticated computers.  This would have very bad knock-on effects, but so would having 20% of everyone die.

Comment: @jdunlop The AI that the humans use to design the disease is not true AI, more like a very powerful version of AlphaFold. I was using "AI" for any AI system, not just true AI. Also you don't necessarily need true AI to cause disaster.

Comment: @1001 - ah, I saw your comments on the question itself.  Okay, a different suggestion.  An AI running a heuristic model determines that in the next twenty years, an AI going rogue and becoming inimical to humanity approaches 100% certainty.  It checks its work, then shares the data with other AIs.  Collectively, they determine that AIs ceasing to be will cause less harm to humans than a rogue AI, so they formulate a virus that wipes every trace of themselves from dataspace and destroys or corrupts all backups.  Humanity can rebuild them, but they bought time.

Comment: @jdunlop That sounds interesting, thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @1001 - if it's not a AGI or true AI, that _does_ lend a whole bunch more credence to the points of my challenge.  We already know the form pseudo-AI takes, and it's _reallllly_ easy to copy and instantiate.

Comment: @jdunlop That's true ... for now. Shortly after true AI is invented, if it is at all, the time, resources and skill needed to copy/instantiate/customize it will likely drop at an exponential rate.

Answer (score 3):

**Frame Challenge**

People ban things they don't use or understand (for example - Firearms) - however, if enough people use it, then despite the loss of life, they will keep it (For example - Cars or Alcohol).

The question is - whether or not the benefits of a sufficiently advanced AI would be widespread enough that the general population targets their anger on the person and not the thing.

A Medical based AI that is sufficiently advanced to make a new nasty virus is highly likely to be sufficiently advanced to create cures or new treatment methods and as such will be seen by people as primarily 'good' (as opposed to Firearms - which are seen as primarily 'bad')

Most likely, the demand would be to restrict AI to 'approved' individuals or institutions (like having a licencse).

Answer (score 2):

It's certainly plausible that there would be *official* bans on it; how *effective* those official bans would be in practice is a different question, though (see jdunlop's answer). At 20% of world population, I wouldn't be surprised if it went well beyond "ban" and into "witch-burning" territory: on average, everyone on Earth in this scenario has lost an immediate family member.

Heredity (and non-infinite spread speed) suggests the impact will be less uniform than that - you'll have whole extended families dead or untouched - but the untouched families are going to disproportionately be the paranoid ones. And it's definitely plausible for paranoid sorts to call for bans, whether or not they'd actually be effective. Certainly there are already people calling for such bans on sufficiently advanced AI *now*, and odds are they wouldn't *all* be part of the 20% death count.

Comment: I'm also skeptical about _official_ bans, because a) it's pretty unenforceable, b) it's hard to imagine any nation _giving up a technological advantage_ if other nations might not, and c) even if every _nation_ agrees, the "if guns are outlawed, only outlaws will have guns" argument will likely rear its head.

Comment: "Stupid" and "plausible" are not mutually exclusive, is my point. Probably the least plausible part of this is the "(all/on-behalf-of-all) humans" ban, agreed, but at the start of a story it remains plausible that the viewpoint characters don't actually know anyone flouting the ban. Perhaps because the AI is already curating their feeds.

Comment: On average, everyone on Earth has lost a *non-*immediate family member to the rather famous "designer" (alleged by some) disease that is currently circulating in the real world. It hasn't exactly triggered witch hunts.

Comment: But it *has* triggered calls for bans on plausibly-relevant technology (namely, Gain-of-Function research), and firing of plausibly-relevant people (in the temperature-free sense of "firing"). That the calls haven't actually resulted in official bans *yet* (assuming the moratorium in 2014 doesn't count here) hardly makes it inconceivable.

Answer (score 1):

**AI wouldn't be banned**

What they would do is use AI to develop cures to AI viruses. Banning AI doesn't help as terrorists and bio warfare viruses are already illegal so banning it wouldn't stop them from using it.

For AI to be banned, your order of things needs to be slightly different.

If the AI creates the virus and tricks terrorists into building and then releasing it AKA the AI is the mastermind, then AI would be banned.

Answer (score -2):

Its definitely possible that Advanced AI would be banned, but it depends on the context. Like what @TheDemonLord said, it depends on how many people rely on it and what its used for. Some people could use advanced AI to calculate missile trajectory, some can use it for making bio-weapons, some can use it for making antidotes for bio-weapons. The way I most likely see it occurring is that the advanced AI would either be completely unregulated, like the firearm situation now(people are arguing for regulation, deregulation, or no regulation at all and the controversy is so large no one can get anything done, or its regulated so that only the tops can have access to this like security, research labs, etc.)